# How to change which display port my graphics card uses to present the Display?

Tags: graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display, displayport

I have a 1080 Ti that I use with my desktop which has one monitor.

I currently use the third slot on the card for the display port, but would like to move the cable over to the first.

When I do so and restart the computer, it loads the bios screen fine, and also the bitlocker password prompt. However, everything after that is not broadcast to the monitor until I unplug the cable and put it back into the 3rd slot.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The display is likely disabled in windows..... check prior to swapping the cable if you can enable all 3 outputs, then switch cable

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: DisplayPort is like USB. A monitor is uninstalled when turned off, and installed when turned on. So it should be enough to boot into windows with the screen attached to the 3rd port, turn off monitor, swap ports, and turn back on. Wait a few seconds for the monitor to install.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what I tried. It did not work, just left me with a blank screen.

Comment: Do you have another machine you can VNC in from, to see what's happening when you swap the monitors over?

Comment: What happens if you swap, then hit WIN+P?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but you tried turning off *before* swapping the cable, right?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all, yes. I tried that.